# Unipotent subgroups and nilpotent subgroups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected complex Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$.  Let $N$ be the maximal nilpotent normal subgroup of $G$. Is the center $Z$ of $N$ unipotent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider the subgroup of diagonal matrices, it is abelian and is not unipotent.

Another example consider the space of $3\times 3$ matrices of the form:

$\pmatrix{a&0&0\cr 0&1&c\cr 0&0&1}$

$\pmatrix{a&0&0\cr 0&1&0\cr 0&0&1}$ is in the center.

Comment: What if $G$ is not abelian, would this change anything?

Comment: But $\pmatrix{a&0&0\cr 0&b&c\cr 0&0&d}$ is not nilpotent?